# jquery css applied but not visible for flex element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I find myself struggling to understand why my approach at recalculating width of an element on resize and seeing the result doesn't work.

Scenario:

I have a flex layout, with 3 unequally wide containers divided into 3/7, 1/7 and 3/7 of the width of the page. I use `width: calc(100%/7)` or `width: calc(100%/7*3)` to let the browser calculate the relation of these containers.

I am aware of the issue that Chrome rounds the calculated values down in case there is an inaccuracy when calculating the relation. This is visible when resizing the browser window as a subpixel-wide white stripe, where the background shines through between the containers on certain widths. Note: this problem does not happen in Firefox, they seem to round these values differently (?).

What I tried:

I used jQuery and `parseFloat(document.getComputedStyle(element).width)` to get the values of the containers and calculate the difference in order to "stretch" the middle container to fill in the gap:

```
jQuery(window).on('resize', function () {
    var mainSite = document.getElementsByClassName('site-main')[0];
    var leftStart = document.getElementsByClassName('page-trigger left')[0];
    var middleStart = document.getElementsByClassName('page-trigger middle')[0];
    var rightStart = document.getElementsByClassName('page-trigger right')[0];

    var mainSiteWidth = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(mainSite).width);
    var leftStartWidth = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(leftStart).width);
    var middleStartWidth = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(middleStart).width);
    var rightStartWidth = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(rightStart).width);

    console.log(mainSiteWidth);
    console.log(leftStartWidth);
    console.log(middleStartWidth);
    console.log(rightStartWidth);

    var calculatedElementWidth = leftStartWidth + middleStartWidth + rightStartWidth

    if (mainSiteWidth > calculatedElementWidth){
        var diff = mainSiteWidth - calculatedElementWidth;
        var newMiddleWidth = middleStartWidth + diff;
        console.log("diff: " + diff);
        console.log("new middle width: " + newMiddleWidth);

        jQuery(middleStart).css({
            flex : "0 0 " + newMiddleWidth + "px",
            width: newMiddleWidth + "px",
            minWidth: newMiddleWidth + "px",
            maxWidth: newMiddleWidth + "px"
        });

        console.log(parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(middleStart).width));

    }
}).resize();
```

So far, the values get correctly calculated and even applied to the `middleStart` element, at least in the DOM inspector, however, the gap is still there, even though the css values indicate, it should have changed.

These were the css settings before the jquery modifications:

```
flex: 0 0 calc(100%/7); --> translates to 273.562px, Chrome shows as 273.56px
width: calc(100%/7); --> translates to 273.562px, Chrome shows as 273.56px
min-width: calc(100%/7); --> translates to 273.562px, Chrome shows as 273.56px
max-width: calc(100%/7); --> translates to 273.562px, Chrome shows as 273.56px
```

These are the values in the DOM inspector after that:

```
flex: 0 0 273.594px;
width: 273.594px;
min-width: 273.594px;
max-width: 273.594px;
```

I tried to create a jsfiddle but I couldn't reproduce that issue there, since my layout is more complex and has more layers.

Does anybody have an idea, why the css settings, though being applied to the element in the DOM, are not visible?

EDIT: this is what happens, try to resize the browser window horizontally (please ignore the occasional jump of the right element, I had to use float:left; to make it reproducable and it only happens in Chrome: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8274e1pj/)

[image: the gap in chrome]

Comment: pls share the `HTML` so that we can understand what's happening here.

Comment: you're right, I added the link to the jsfiddle